# Dictionary inside a dictionary from csv

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I'm very very new to python (only been coding for a few months) and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around a dictionary inside a dictionary.

I have a list of journals and bunch of information around them from a csv (so the first line are headings) and basically I want a dictionary that is {journal name:{heading:value}. The journal name is the second string in the line (after the headings).

I just can't comprehend how I can do this after opening the csv. All help is appreciated!

```
f = open('journals.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
rows = []
for row in csv_f:
    rows.append(row)
    headings = rows[0] #these are the headings from the csv
    info = rows[1:] #these are the rest of the rows

dict6 = {}
dict7 = {}
for row in info:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        dict6[headings[i]] = row[i]
    dict7[row[0]] = dict6
'''this is working to be correct except it is matching the wrong journal name to the wrong values(dict6)

Right now I can't seem to make an if statement to match the list of journal ids to the journal id key in order to match it to the inner dictionary'''
```

Comment: Do you have existing code? How about a few line sample csv with header?

Comment: Indeed, as @tdelaney mentions, sample lines of the csv would help.

Comment: I added some of my code right now.

Answer (score 0):

`csv.DictReader` reads CSV lines into dictionaries. That takes care of the inner dict. You can build the outer dict with a comprehension that takes one item in the row for the key.

Assuming a csv file of

```
foo,bar,baz
1,thing1,2
2,thing2,3
4,thing3,5
```

you could

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('test.csv', newline='') as fp:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
...     outer_dict = {row['bar']:row for row in reader}
... 
>>> outer_dict
{'thing1': {'bar': 'thing1', 'foo': '1', 'baz': '2'}, 'thing3': {'bar': 'thing3', 'foo': '4', 'baz': '5'}, 'thing2': {'bar': 'thing2', 'foo': '2', 'baz': '3'}}
```